# How to change the background color of second "ul" element in php for loop?

Tags: php, css

I'm not php programmer, but need to change something in php code that looks as following:

```
{% for recent_topics in loops.recent_topics %}
{% if not recent_topics.S_TOPIC_TYPE_SWITCH and not recent_topics.S_FIRST_ROW %}
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endif %}

{% if recent_topics.S_FIRST_ROW or not recent_topics.S_TOPIC_TYPE_SWITCH %}
<a class="category{% if S_EXT_COLCAT_HIDDEN %} hidden-category{% endif %}" style="display: none; height: 0"></a>
<div id="recent-topics-box" class="forabg recent-topics">
<div class="inner">
<ul class="topiclist">
    <li class="header">
        <dl class="row-item">
            <dt><div class="list-inner">{{ lang('RECENT_TOPICS') }}</div></dt>
            <dd class="posts">{{ lang('REPLIES') }}</dd>
            <dd class="views">{{ lang('VIEWS') }}</dd>
            <dd class="lastpost"><span>{{ lang('LAST_POST') }}</span></dd>
        </dl>
        <a href="{{ U_EXT_COLCAT_COLLAPSE_URL }}"
           class="collapse-btn collapse-{% if S_EXT_COLCAT_HIDDEN %}show{% else %}hide{% endif %}"
           data-hidden="{{ S_EXT_COLCAT_HIDDEN }}"
           data-ajax="phpbb_collapse"
           data-overlay="true"
           title="{{ lang('COLLAPSIBLE_CATEGORIES_TITLE') }}"
           style="display: none; line-height: 0;"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

That's the part of the code of the extension in phpBB forum's software. The forum looks as following:

[image]

I need to change the background of header of second "ul" list (below).

The key point is in CSS file that is located in theme I use:

```
ul.topiclist  {
    background-color: #6AC07D;
}
```

The issue is all "ul" headers in forum are green because of setting in CSS file including "ul" header in extension.

Comment: Find the element using the inspector/dev tools in your browser, and then target that element using CSS.

Comment: Please can you show the rendered html structure

Comment: you probably need [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

Comment: @giorgio that probably won't work as the ul are not siblings

Comment: I've tried :nth approach, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Mike, I'm not 100% sure what you mean. I've tried to play with it, but no success. Maybe I've played in wrong way.

Comment: @Mike, If I understand you correctly, I've found ul.topiclist in CSS file and changed the background color, but all "ul" headers changed background color to new color, not only recent topics.

Comment: That is correct, however you need to limit the scope of that selector, using `ul.topiclist` isn't specific enough. You will need to add another class to just the recent topics so then you can do something like `ul.topiclist .recent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a `recent-topics-box` div wrapping your desired content, so you could use that and then just add another style for it in your CSS:

```
#recent-topics-box ul.topiclist {
  background-color: #222;
}
```

By doing this, you're preserving every other use of `topiclist` while customizing this particular one.

Comment: I'm happy that it works. Sorry for editing the answer, I hadn't noticed that div ID initially